# How to save to a link List?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm lost. I made a link List and I want to save data into it.
When people type in their names, I want it to save in the link List.

I suspect it's a matter of pointing at pointers, but I'm not used to the tactic I used for getting input for the get char and such. The voided code (not a struct) is OUTSIDE of int main(), I've never coded outside of int main() until now.

In the int main() function is my code for the linkList.

So I want to call the function outside of int main into int main, and point a pointer to the name. How do I go at doing this?

Thank ya much,
TG52.

Comment: I don't think people will be able to help you without your code or what you've tried. May also be worth tagging this as Java as that seems to be the language you're coding in.

Comment: @DavidBarker: I didn't know we have `int main()` in Java as well

Comment: @Aamir lols maybe I should learn both of them :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your code and what's your problem?

I know of a lot of list implementation you might consider 
Check out the implementation of the glib (or even better do use the glib)

http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.33/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html

You can download complete sources of diverse collections from:

http://code.google.com/p/ccl/

If you insist on doing it yourself you should at least show us what you've done so far.